# How do I update the sorted dict as well as the original dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary, variables, append

Once i append another value into the dict it updates the roster. As expected. Yet, once i try and output the sorted roster it doesnt update? How can I fix this?

I tried by:

```
    roster = [
    {"jersey_number": player_1, "rating": rating_1},
    {"jersey_number": player_2, "rating": rating_2},
    {"jersey_number": player_3, "rating": rating_3},
    {"jersey_number": player_4, "rating": rating_4},
    {"jersey_number": player_5, "rating": rating_5},
]

print("ROSTER")
sorted_roster = sorted(roster, key=lambda x: x["jersey_number"])
for player in sorted_roster:
    print("Jersey number: {}, Rating: {}".format(player["jersey_number"], player["rating"]))
```

and then later:

```
elif choice == "a":
      jersey_number = int(input("Enter Jersey number:\n"))
      rating = int(input("Enter rating:\n"))
      newplayer = {"jersey_number": jersey_number, "rating": rating}
      roster.append(newplayer)
      print("new player added")
```

but once i asked the computer to output the updated roster:

```
elif choice == "o":
        # Output roster
        print("ROSTER")
        for player in sorted_roster:
            print("Jersey number: {}, Rating: {}".format(player["jersey_number"], player["rating"]))
```

i got the same original roster back without the added values.
How can i get sorted_roster_ to update and stay sorted. Shouldnt it automatically update since its based off the variable (roster)?

Sorry, im obviously really new to programming itself and have been stuck on this single thing for quite a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making `sorted_roster` a function:

```
def sorted_roster():
    return sorted(roster, key=lambda x: x["jersey_number"])

for player in sorted_roster():
    print("Jersey number: {}, Rating: {}".format(player["jersey_number"], player["rating"]))
```

If you make it a function, each time you call it with the `()` operator the body of the function is evaluated and the list is re-built.  (Note that this is far from the most *efficient* way to do it, but for now the important thing is to understand the difference between data that's built dynamically by a function call and static data that you assign to a variable.)

If you only call `sorted()` once and assign its result to a variable, you just get the list that `sorted()` returned that first time; the original function isn't going to get automatically called again each time you access the result.